# How to start IPFS in browser by using only DHT WebRTC peers?

Tags: ipfs

I'm using this code in the browser. It seems to be connecting to ipfs.io via http?. I'm looking to only connect to DHT webRTC peers. I'm guessing I need to pass some option to Ipfs.create? I see an example of custom libp2p here but the amount of options are overwhelming. https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/examples/custom-libp2p/index.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ipfs/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (async () => {
        const node = await Ipfs.create()

        const data = 'Hello'
        const results = await node.add(data)
        console.log(results)
    })()
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the IPFS config options when creating the instance, which enables you to specify the remote WebRTC addresses you want to listen on, and remove/change the Bootstrap nodes to initially connect to. You can see this in the file exchange example at https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/ipfs%400.49.1/examples/browser-exchange-files/public/app.js#L48. So your config might look like this:

```
const node = await Ipfs.create({
  config: {
    Addresses: {
      Swarm: [
        // These are public webrtc-star servers
        '/dns4/wrtc-star1.par.dwebops.pub/tcp/443/wss/p2p-webrtc-star',
        '/dns4/wrtc-star2.sjc.dwebops.pub/tcp/443/wss/p2p-webrtc-star'
      ]
    },
    // This removes the default IPFS peers to dial to. You can specify any known addresses you wish, or leave blank.
    Bootstrap: []
  }
})
```

As you've mentioned the DHT I just want to note that running a DHT over WebRTC is really not viable outside of a small, isolated network. As WebRTC dialing can take some time, this has a huge impact on DHT query times.

Comment: thanks, I tried testing it, but I can't figure out how to actually get some logs about what's going on under the hood. how can I console log which peers are connecting and their status and whatnot, so that I can verify that your answer works? I did try looking at the docs https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/SWARM.md but I'm not seeing events to attach to.

Comment: You can hook into libp2p directly, which will give you more access to those type of events. libp2p is accessible at `node.libp2p` and you can take a look at the available events in the docs, https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/blob/master/doc/API.md#events.